# Remove key from list

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

i'm working on a small function for selling software license keys. Basically what it does is it gets keys from a txt, and then it grabs a key and deletes the file, rewrites it but without the key that was sold. I've got a issue though. Could anyone help me spot the error and perhaps help me fix it?

file.txt contents:

```
KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY4, KEY5
```

My class:

```
class Key {

 public static function getRandomKey($keyset)
 {
    $i = rand(0, count($keyset));
    return $keyset[$i];
 }

}
```

My function:

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$contents = str_replace(' ', '', $contents);
$keyset = explode(',', $contents);
$key = Key::getRandomKey($keyset);
echo $key;
$str = implode(',', $keyset);
unlink($file);
$rfile = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($rfile, $str);
fclose($rfile);
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this in a file? Using a database would make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: @andrewsi I will use a database when the project is up, for testing purposes i am using a file.

Comment: well your not testing what you will actully be doing in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd side with [*@andrewsi's comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236891/remove-key-from-list#comment63895183_38236891), but the general flow of how you want to achieve this is as such:

```
// fetch
$keys = file_get_contents('your_keys.txt');
// explode
$list = explode(",", $keys);
// get random key (this would be your Key::getRandomKey() function)
$use = rand(0, (count($list) - 1)); // notice how we do count($list) - 1? Since the index starts at 0, not 1, you need to account for that ;-)

// now get a key
echo $list[$use];
// unset that key from the list
unset($list[$use]);
// implode the keys again
$keys = implode(", ",$list);
// and save it to the file
file_put_contents('your_keys.txt', $keys);
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#0fWzCNpya)

Comment: You can use `array_rand`, `$use = àrray_rand($list)`

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH you 100% could (*and it'd probably be the easier solution*) - was sticking to OP's original question scope :)

Comment: Thanks, your code is working, just to expand my knowledge did you actually spot the error? Also i changed the code to array_rand

Comment: @Stunked You never removed it from the original `$keyset` array - notice how i use `unset()` ? After that, writing it to the file :)

Comment: @Darren Thank you!

Comment: That's alright @Stunked - It's always the small issues that we miss!